# Using a Between validator on addElement() in a Zend_Form class

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

I'm building a basic Zend_Form in Zend 1.12 to take birth dates and hire dates of new employees. I'd like to do a very basic validation on the dates - at this time I'm not concerned about nonsense dates like a February 30th; I just want to get ranges like 1900-9999, 1-12, 1-31 going on the individual input fields.

The form will load with the code below, but with a valid year (1982) or not (2), I get an application error on submission: "Missing option. 'min' and 'max' has to be given"

I think I'm not getting the syntax right.

```
$this->addElement('text', 'byear', array(
        'label'      => 'Birth Date :: Year:',
        'required'   => true,
        'style' => 'width:75px;',
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'decorators' => array('Label',
        'ViewHelper'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('Between', 1900, 9999))
    ));
```

This doesn't work either:

```
'validators' => array(array('Between', 'min' => 1900, 'max' => 9999))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
'validators' => array(
    array('Between', false, array('min' => 1900, 'max' => 9999))
 )
```

Comment: OK, I got that too. Just need to stick in 'Error' inside my decorators array.